# Artifactory large downloads failing

Tags: wget, artifactory, large-files

My continuing saga:

I have *Artifactory Pro 5.8.4* running on a *CentOS 7.4* system that uses Artifactory's built-in *Nginx* service as a reverse proxy. Most of the time, during download of a large object, **the connection fails**. Additionally, the last few kilobytes of data that are transferred in the failed connection appear to be garbage; as a result, the file, when resumed, has a section in the middle somewhere that is invalid.
Nginx logs around the time of failure provide the following error message:

> 2018/01/22 23:26:32 [error] 884#0: *48048865 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 12.2.178.130, server: ~(?.+).artifactory.common.mycoolco.com, request: "GET /controller/release/20171218-2119-2aa9f0e8c32bf3f08dd96a97127204d1f400f895fa2e67100a3830861c0becb0bfae28244c058510c8312e98378c0b77251b4bb7926ceae2d465ce2d533b88dc HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/artifactory/controller/release/20171218-2119-2aa9f0e8c32bf3f08dd96a97127204d1f400f895fa2e67100a3830861c0becb0bfae28244c058510c8312e98378c0b77251b4bb7926ceae2d465ce2d533b88dc", host: "artifactory.common.mycoolco.com"

The Artifactory logs usually, but not always, have an error that looks something like this:

> 2018-01-22 23:14:20,106 [http-nio-8081-exec-87] [WARN ] (o.a.r.ArtifactoryResponseBase:137) - Client Closed Request 499: java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Any further suggestions for diagnosis would be appreciated.

THIS DID NOT AFFECT ANY NOTICEABLE CHANGE:
As a follow-through, I will be changing some settings for testing over this weekend (SUN, MAR. 18TH) during my maintenance window by editing the nginx.conf file (/etc/opt/rh/rh-nginx18/nginx/nginx.conf) to contain the settings "worker_processes 2" (was currently 1), upping worker connections from 1024 to 2048 and changing the keepalive_timeout from 65 to 130.

We have a single Artifactory instance hosted in AWS with no other proxies nor load balancers; just a single instance and a route 53 entry pointing to the private ip address. We are seeing a baseline 10%cpu usage with spikes to 100% every 15 minutes ...apparently from the from the java process. java -version: openjdk version "1.8.0_161" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode). now on artifactory.version: 5.8.4

```
> --2018-03-08 22:09:42--  https://artifactory.common.mycoolco.com/controller/pre-release/20180308-2216-023a0b8309af8889
Resolving artifactory.common.mycoolco.com (artifactory.common.mycoolco.com)... 55.111.66.99
Connecting to artifactory.common.mycoolco.com (artifactory.common.mycoolco.com)|55.111.66.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1241911191 (1.2G) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘20180308-2216-023a0b8309af8889’

20180308-2216-c3499ea023a0b8309  86%[=============================================>        ]   1.00G   568KB/s    in 1m 31s 

2018-03-08 22:30:14 (857 KB/s) - Connection closed at byte 1079774172. Retrying.

--2018-03-08 22:30:15--  (try: 2)  https://artifactory.common.mycoolco.com/controller-os/pre-release/20180308-2216-023a0b8309af8889
Connecting to artifactory.common.mycoolco.com (artifactory.common.mycoolco.com)|55.111.66.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 1241911191 (1.2G), 162137019 (155M) remaining [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘20180308-2216-023a0b8309af8889’

20180308-2216-c3499ea023a0b8309 100%[++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++=======>]   1.16G  1.08MB/s    in 0m 22s  

2018-03-08 22:32:38 (1.09 MB/s) - ‘20180308-2216-023a0b8309af8889’ saved [1241911191/1241911191]
```

[top command showing java high cpu usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOHk5.png)
[AWS cpu spikes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Voe3K.png)

Comment: Are you downloading the file from local or remote repository?

Comment: Remote.  We host our Artifactory Instance in AWS, and access from multiple remote locations.  Our Artifactory instance has worked flawlessly for a little over a year (since Aug/2016) until this issue surfaced in mid-January.

Comment: My apologies, I had mis-interpreted your question.  It is a local repo.

Comment: @user5905820 Do you have any kind of proxy/firewall/load balancer between your Artifactory installation on AWS and the client? by the error it looks like something in the middle decided to cut the communication. The garbage you are seeing might be produced by this tool (maybe an error message?)

Comment: @Dror-Bereznitsky Artifactory appears to come with nginx installed, but I do not see any settings which need tuning.  We have a single Artifactory instance hosted in AWS with no other proxies nor load balancers;  just a simple a route 53 entry pointing to the private ip address.  We are seeing a baseline 10%cpu usage with spikes to 100% every 15 minutes ...apparently from the from the java process.  java -version:  openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode).  now on artifactory.version:  5.8.4

Comment: @user5905820 when communicating with Artifactory from inside your organization, are you sure users does not have to go through a firewall or a corporate proxy? in most cases some rule in those tools is cutting down the communication

Comment: Yes:  we have a small user base of ~200 controllers in the field (across the US) and everyone is incurring this failure...both inside and outside our corporate network, I also see it from home on my home network.  The Artifactory instance is in AWS and that local instance has an inactive firewall.  The AWS security groups allow all inbound http and https transfers from anywhere, and the outbound rules allow all.

Comment: As a workaround, if you are stucked unable to download the file, application like Free Download Manager was helpful in downloading the file. However, this doesn't resolves or provides a workaround to fix the problem on the backend. Sharing this if someone like me is stucked waiting to download a file without having control on the backend server.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Sadly my issue was with production client devices in the field failing to download new packages.  We finally worked around the issue by 1) using wget 2) truncating 1M off the end of any failed wget download and then 3) Continue the download until finished.

Comment: Here is a similar bash code snippet strongly resembling my solution:

    `until ( \`$wget_cmd --tries=1 --continue "${docker_image_url}/${new_image_name}"\` || [ $wget_count -le 0 ] ); do
    log_this "Resuming truncated image download"
    let "wget_count--"
    truncate -s -1M "${image_name}"
  done`

Answer (score 6):

The issue could be due to ​[proxy_max_temp_file_size](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_max_temp_file_size). The default value is 1GB. Check if `proxy_max_temp_file_size 0` helps.

Comment: That might be worth trying, but I'd be surprised if the file size limit could cause a socket timeout exception, especially one the server is blaming on the client?

Comment: Thank you @sky67, I will try it adding a large value to the proxy_max_temp_file_size variable during my next scheduled downtime.

Comment: Max temp file size set to 0 fixed an issue with local repo also. The issue could be tested with command `curl --user <user> --limit-rate 2m --output package.zip https://<artifactory_url>/package.zip`. The connection would close around 1034M without adding the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

By the error message, it seems that the issue is the 'Socket Timeout (MS)' parameter on your remote repository (as you mentioned in your comment). 
In order to resolve the issue go to Artifactory UI --> Remote repositories --> Edit the repository that is having the issue --> Go to Advanced Tab --> Edit the 'Socket Timeout (MS)' param and extend it.

If this is not a remote repository but local repository on a remote instance, it probably an issue with the proxy in front of Artifactory.

Comment: Thank you Ariel, I will dig in to the installations NGINX config; I found my repo in the UI's local repositories tab.  I am fairly new to Artifactory, but I know that my highly-skilled team has already been attempting to determine the root cause for a few months... We're stumped.  Thanks again:  Highly appreciated.

Comment: Good luck mate.

Comment: Nginx did not have many settings and upping the variables as I described in my above post did nothing noticeable.

Comment: Artifactory doesn't cut/terminate downloads from Local Repository. It doesn't have the option to... The issue is 99.9% at the proxy/firewall level.

Comment: Thank you once again, @Ariel.  I am at wit's end.  This issue is causing most of my users downloads to fail.  The local firewall is off, and aws s3 rules have not been changed in many months; they allow everyone http and https access.  The only potential proxy is the built-in nginx server in artifactory, but i do not see the nginx service in the local process' list, and modifications to the nginx.conf file have not affected any noticeable changes.  Sadly I cannot afford support, so I am basically blocked until I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Just to make sure, what do you mean by "built-in nginx server"? Artifactory doesn't have build in Nginx instance.

Comment: For clarification, since I have gone off into the sticks, the original content of the post was created by my senior devops engineer and I assumed his story was correct.  I DO see the nginx service running on the artifactory server, and have upped the numbers of worker connections, worker_processes and the keepalive_timeout, to no avail -- and do not see any other settings which would limit a file size nor cause a timeout in either the nginx conf file (/etc/opt/rh/rh-nginx18/nginx/nginx.conf) nor the artifactory conf files.  (/etc/opt/rh/rh-nginx18/nginx/conf.d/artifactory.conf)

Comment: You should also check and add the following params to Nginx:
proxy_read_timeout XXX;
 proxy_connect_timeout  XXX;
proxy_send_timeout XXX;

Comment: We already had a proxy_read_timeout of 900 seconds.  I have added, and then removed the suggested settings:  they caused Artifactory to fail to load.   
#    proxy_connect_timeout 75;
#    proxy_send_timeout 75;