# cURL problem downloading files larger than 1gb from artifactory

Tags: curl, artifactory

I have a problem with cURL, when downloading files larger than 1gb from our corporate artifactory. It seems to fail as soon as it reaches 1gb, before it works as expected.
There is no problem with PowerShell (scoop), nor with chrome and also no problem with wget. The installed cURL is the latest greatest 64bit version from scoop, older from September last year has the same behaviour.
cmake file(download...) Fails the same way like cURL, but I think it also uses cURL lib for downloads. Using cmake internal download function was my motivation. Right now my only workaround is to use wget in a execute_program step.

Is this a cURL issue? Settings or arguments? Or is there any problem with artifactory? Any way to get complete files with cURL?

Comment: worth a check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145372/artifactory-large-downloads-failing. It is for sure related to artifactory

Comment: thanks for the hint, gonna check this.

Comment: @error404 setting `proxy_max_temp_file_size 0` worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @error404 pointed out, the solution of [Artifactory large downloads failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145372/artifactory-large-downloads-failing) by setting

```
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0
```

did also help in my case.